# NginX 500 (Internal Server) Error

Tags: php, macos, nginx

I've been having some problems with my NginX installation. I'm not getting any errors, however, I get the classic "500 - Internal Server Error" when I try to go to my localhost address.

This is my config:

```
user       nobody;  ## Default: nobody
worker_processes  5;  ## Default: 1
error_log  logs/error.log;
pid        logs/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}

http {
include    mime.types;
include    fastcgi.conf;
index    index index.html index.htm index.php;

default_type application/octet-stream;
log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
'"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
'"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
access_log   logs/access.log  main;
sendfile     on;
tcp_nopush   on;
server_names_hash_bucket_size 128; # this seems to be required for some vhosts

server { # simple reverse-proxy
listen       80;
access_log   logs/access.log  main;

# serve static files
location ~ ^/(images|javascript|js|css|flash|media|static)/  {
root    /Library/Testing/public_html;
expires 30d;
}

# pass requests for dynamic content to rails/turbogears/zope, et al
location / {
proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
}

upstream big_server_com {
server 127.0.0.3:8000 weight=5;
server 127.0.0.3:8001 weight=5;
server 192.168.0.1:8000;
server 192.168.0.1:8001;
}

server { # simple load balancing
listen          80;
server_name     big.server.com;
access_log      logs/big.server.access.log main;

location / {
proxy_pass      http://big_server_com;
}
}
}
```

What's the issue? I looked at other related SOF questions, but none fixed my problem. Thank you.

EDIT: My log is now saying: `2015/07/26 13:43:40 [error] 2494#0: *1 kevent() reported that connect() failed (61: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.php", host: "localhost"`

When I attempt to load the page "localhost/index.php"

Comment: Are you sure PHP isn't throwing an error? Anythings in the nginx error log?

Comment: @Will - How can I check the PHP error log? nginx doesn't seem to be saying anything useful.

Comment: Run `php --info | grep error` . Look for `error_log` and `log_errors`. Make sure `log_errors` is on in php.ini and specify a path to a log file in `error_log`.

Comment: I enabled log_errors, and for error_log I set the default path: "php_errors.log" php_errors.log doesn't appear to be generating.

Comment: You need to specify an absolute path to the error log. Try `/var/log/php_errors.log`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue. It turns out I forgot to activate php-fpm: `sudo php-fpm` does the trick.

Comment: Ah, I see. So your backend was down.